# Search javascript in Django

Tags: javascript, django, search, browser

I have the following javascript code to do a search (search with a button in the bar) on a page in Django 2.2, it works but it highlights it for less than 1 second, that is, it finds the word highlights it and no longer highlights it anymore As I said it does less than 1 second and the idea is that it is checked and if possible that it continues showing other coincidences like CTRL + F does in browsers. Can someone help me with a code that does work well? Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function FindNext () {
    var str = document.getElementById ("findInput").value;
    if (str == "") {
      alert ("Por favor, introduzca un texto para buscar!");
      return;
    }

    if (window.find) {        // Firefox, Google Chrome, Safari
      var found = window.find (str);
      if (!found) {
        alert ("No se encontró el siguiente texto:\n" + str);
      }
    }
    else {
      alert ("Su navegador no es compatible!");
    }
  }
</script>
```